# C++ compiler command c++ does not generate output

Tags: c++, unix, gist, nano

I have written a C++ file in `nano` text editor (UNIX command line) and I am trying to execute it with this command: `c++ main.cpp`. When I run it, no error messages display, however, there's also no successful messages; simply nothing appears... I also tried `clang` which gave me some more details, click [here](https://gist.github.com/DudekJoshua/89b075b7d445efe7371327e0958c9988) to view the error message.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Clang Output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-ad7332.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-ad7332.o: in function `__cxx_global_var_init':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x19): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: `c++ main.cpp` does not *run* anything. It just compiles a source file into an object file (or executable). You have to subsequently link the object file with other object files to form an executable and then run it. Or if you are directly generating an executable, just run it.

Comment: you need to run `clang++` not `clang` for c++ code

Comment: No output for `c++ main.cpp` should be the expected as there is nothing wrong with the given code for the compiler to report. Check for an a.out file that can be run.The error from clang suggests clang is not looking in the correct place, or not looking at all,  for the standard library  implementation. Asking how to correct this problem should be a reasonable question. Make sure you include the full command line you are using.

Comment: [First Time To Run C++ Program on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552734/first-time-to-run-c-program-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No output whatsoever is the expected outcome. Running `c++` only *compiles* the provided source file. To run your program, you will have to explicitly run the produced executable, which by default is `a.out`.

With regards to the error messages you received from `clang`, make sure that you are using `clang++` and remembered to include the `iostream` header, which declares `std::cout`.